# Jenkins GitHub Webhook not working

Tags: linux, github, jenkins-plugins

I am running Jenkins 2.89.4 on the official Docker LTS image in an Amazon Linux EC2 instance. I am using the GitHub webhook and when I test it I get this on the docker logs;

```
Feb 20, 2018 4:48:23 PM io.relution.jenkins.awssqs.logging.Log write
INFO: 000380 Create new SQSTriggerQueue(8d894fcf-becd-449c-a65b-2a404c57b7bc, , )
Feb 20, 2018 4:48:23 PM hudson.plugins.scm_sync_configuration.ScmSyncConfigurationBusiness queueChangeSet
INFO: Queue of changeset     A hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.xml
    A jenkins.model.ArtifactManagerConfiguration.xml
    A hudson.tasks.Shell.xml
    A scm-sync-configuration.xml
    A hudson.tasks.Mailer.xml
    A config.xml
    A jenkins.plugins.awslogspublisher.AWSLogsConfig.xml
    A hudson.plugins.jira.JiraProjectProperty.xml
    A hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.xml
    A jenkins.metrics.api.MetricsAccessKey.xml
    A hudson.plugins.timestamper.TimestamperConfig.xml
    A jenkins.model.JenkinsLocationConfiguration.xml
    A hudson.plugins.build_timeout.operations.BuildStepOperation.xml
    A hudson.triggers.SCMTrigger.xml
    A hudson.plugins.emailext.ExtendedEmailPublisher.xml
    A hudson.maven.MavenModuleSet.xml
 aborted (scm manipulator not settled !)
Feb 20, 2018 4:49:03 PM com.squareup.okhttp.internal.Platform$JdkWithJettyBootPlatform getSelectedProtocol
INFO: ALPN callback dropped: SPDY and HTTP/2 are disabled. Is alpn-boot on the boot class path?
```

Comment: Try asking on the [Jenkins User group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/jenkinsci-users).